# Why is my glm still analyzing muliple variables when I use as.factor()?

Tags: r, glm

I am trying to run a glm that looks at the effects of food type, habitat, and starvation period on food preference in Ants, however I simply want to look at food type as a single factor, even though I provide the ants with 5 foods. I have used as.factor on the food variable, but it still doesn't seem to work! I want a single p-value for how food affects individuals. Am I missing something?

```
  NumofAnts FoodType Trial SiteType
1         0     Pink     1  natural
2         4     Pink     1  natural
3         5     Pink     1  natural
4         4     Pink     1  natural
5         8     Pink     1  natural
6         5     Pink     1  natural
```

```
fit<-glm(NumofAnts~as.factor(FoodType) + Trial + SiteType, 
family=poisson(link=log), data=stacked1)
```

```
glm(formula = NumofAnts ~ as.factor(FoodType) + Trial + SiteType, 
    family = poisson(link = log), data = stacked1)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.5644  -2.2495  -1.0023   0.8588   8.8051  

Coefficients:
                          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                1.46177    0.08031  18.202  < 2e-16 ***
as.factor(FoodType)Blue   -0.66665    0.06824  -9.769  < 2e-16 ***
as.factor(FoodType)Green  -0.29987    0.06093  -4.922 8.57e-07 ***
as.factor(FoodType)Yellow -0.28086    0.06060  -4.635 3.57e-06 ***
as.factor(FoodType)Red    -0.92502    0.07459 -12.401  < 2e-16 ***
Trial                      0.19355    0.04327   4.473 7.73e-06 ***
SiteTypeurban             -0.19730    0.04328  -4.558 5.16e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: It doesn't look like your `FoodType` variable is ordinal, so the current dummy coding approach looks appropriate. You *can* fit a model with and without `FoodType`included, and compare them using `anova` to see what the overall impact of including the terms though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A glm will estimate one coefficient (so one p-value) when the variable is numeric. But when the variable is categoric (like `food` on your case) it will calculate one coefficient for each level (except one) of your variable. In your case, `food` has 5 levels so 4 coefficients are estimated (so 4 p-values).